# Which first edition is the "true" first edition of a book?

Tags: textual-history, publishing, book-collecting

I've come across books that have multiple first editions that were all published in the same year. For example, the Silmarillion was published in 1977 in a first UK edition, first export edition, and a first US edition. Although using that as an example, there are other books that are considered collectable, but they have similar publication patterns (printed in various first editions around the same time). In cases such as this, how do you determine which edition is the true first edition? What if they are printed simultaneously on the same date in various countries, then how is the true first edition determined?